# Changing google translate font size with chrome extention?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-translate

Is it possible to change the font-size of the input language textbox of [google translate](http://translate.google.com/) with a chrome extension?

Arabic and many other languages look too small for me. I would like to have the ability to set the font-size myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was possible and there was already an extension that could do that. [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) is a good one. Thanks